# Struggling to use FindMinimum function

Tags: differential-equations

I am interested to solve two coupled 2nd order differential equations (see the link below). Given a working precision (wp), I would like to determine the initial condition (v0) for which the square of the "error" is minimum. Given the v0 and wp the function SSE returns the square of the error. However, I am struggling with FindMinimum function to get the final results (i.e. The value of v0 in the range [vmin, vmax] for which the square of the "error" is minimum which is expected to be very close to zero. Please help me to find any syntax error in notebook.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sQdGa2RfOhOV5WCSEgYdcN5phTYEDJ7s/view?usp=drive_web[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sQdGa2RfOhOV5WCSEgYdcN5phTYEDJ7s/view?usp=drive_web)

Regards,
Soumen

Comment: While there might be other issues in your code, the error message "Initial condition v0 is not a number or a rectangular array of numbers." means that `v0` is not a number or a rectangular array of numbers.  Changing `{v0, {-20422/10000, -20420/10000}}` to `{{v0, -20422/10000}}` gets you farther along.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have checked the function (SSE) with different set of values of v0 and wp parameters. It works fine. Is there any error in the syntax of FindMInimum part.

Comment: It is possible that there are no errors, but in this combination the code does not work. I can show the working code that solves this problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is the working code that solves the problem. But I had to give up all the excesses.

```
wp = 14; t3 = 12; x0 = 
 994/1000; init3 = {x[0] == x0, y[0] == 0, Derivative[1][x][0] == 0, 
  Derivative[1][y][0] == v0};
ode = {(x^\[Prime]\[Prime])[
    t] == -((500 (x[t] - 40657/41157))/(
     41157 ((x[t] - 40657/41157)^2 + y[t]^2)^(3/2))) + x[t] + 
    2 Derivative[1][y][t] - (40657 (x[t] + 500/41157))/(
    41157 ((x[t] + 500/41157)^2 + y[t]^2)^(3/2)), (
    y^\[Prime]\[Prime])[
    t] == -((500 y[t])/(
     41157 ((x[t] - 40657/41157)^2 + y[t]^2)^(3/2))) + y[t] - 
    2 Derivative[1][x][t] - (40657 y[t])/(
    41157 ((x[t] + 500/41157)^2 + y[t]^2)^(3/2))}; ode3 = 
 ode \[Union] init3;
x3 = ParametricNDSolveValue[ode3, x, {t, 0, t3}, {v0}]; y3 = 
 ParametricNDSolveValue[ode3, y, {t, 0, t3}, {v0}];

f[v0_, t_] := {x3[v0][t] - x0, y3[v0][t], Derivative[1][x3][v0][t], 
    Derivative[1][y3][v0][t] - v0}.{x3[v0][t] - x0, y3[v0][t], 
    Derivative[1][x3][v0][t], Derivative[1][y3][v0][t] - v0};
tf[v0_] := t /. FindRoot[y3[v0][t] == 0, {t, 11}];
tfi = Interpolation[
    Table[{v0, tf[v0]}, {v0, -2.5, -1.9, .01}]]; // Quiet
 vopt = 
 FindMinimum[f[v0, tfi[v0]], {v0, -2}, WorkingPrecision -> wp] // 
   Timing // Quiet

Out[10]= {98.875, {43.640200866034, {v0 -> -1.9887008931950}}}
```